# How to set RANDOM in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, random, exe

So i wrote this batch file.

I need to use some kind of random function to choose between 9 .exe fles.

One of those .exe files is "OPTION1.exe", so i'd like the batch to select from "OPTION2.exe, OPTION3.exe..." etc, which are all located in the same folder as the first one.

I'd like to know if it's possible and how to do it.

Thanks for your time.

```
@echo off
:loop
TASKKILL /F /IM "Software.exe"
TASKKILL /F /IM "Chrome.exe"
TIMEOUT /T 5
cd C:\Users\admin\Documents\Software
start Software
TIMEOUT /T 15
start OPTION1.exe
TIMEOUT /T 10
start connect.exe
TIMEOUT /T 15
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
start Chrome.exe 
TIMEOUT /T 400
TASKKILL /F /IM "Chrome.exe"
TIMEOUT /T 10
cd C:\Users\admin\Documents\Software
start disconnect.exe
TIMEOUT /T 15
cls
GOTO loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set /a executable=(%random% %% 9) + 1
set "executablename=OPTION%executable%.exe"
echo %executablename%
```

should show you a random executable name `OPTION1.exe` .. `OPTION9.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few improvements that you can make to the code you provided. Here is the modified code:

```
echo off
cls
:loop
TASKKILL /F /IM Software.exe
TASKKILL /F /IM Chrome.exe
TIMEOUT /T 5
cd C:\Users\admin\Documents\Software
start Software.exe
TIMEOUT /T 15
start OPTION1.exe
start OPTION2.exe
start OPTION3.exe
TIMEOUT /T 10
start connect.exe
TIMEOUT /T 15
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
start Chrome.exe 
TIMEOUT /T 400
TASKKILL /F /IM Chrome.exe
TIMEOUT /T 10
cd C:\Users\admin\Documents\Software
start disconnect.exe
TIMEOUT /T 15
cls
GOTO :loop
```